# How to implement a timer callback that executes in the same execution context

Tags: c++, timer, thread-safety

Some programming environments like C++ builder have timer components with a callback function which executes in the same execution contexts as where the timer object is created.

I was wondering how to do something similar in plain c++ with threading. 
Or are there any other ways to have a callback which is periodically called to perform some task and runs in the same execution context as the calling thread?

Comment: I think C++ builder's timers do not use threads for executing destined function.

Comment: Sorry I never worked with C++ builder, what is the meaning of same execution context?

Comment: I mean within the same thread as the timer object was created. Basically no need to worry about protection of shared data. If I create a thread from within a class to do some periodic work, I have to take care with the access of local vars within the same class.

Comment: @Waldorf: In C++ builder, Timer has no problem with shared data because it runs the callbacks sequential not parallel(thread).

Answer (score 0):

Whether or no a thread can process a timer callback within its own context depends entirely on how the timer expiry can be communicated to the thread.  The thread must call the callback itself upon the receipt of some inter-thread comms, (eg. a WM_TIMER message received by a Windows GUI thread when it is waiting on its Windows message queue input).  If the thread is not waiting for input, it cannot handle any inter-thread comms from any kind of timer and so cannot call any timer-handler callback within its own context.

Forms.Timer, the C++ builder Timer component and other such are ways of arranging for interval-based inter-thread notifications - if a thread does not actively wait for and handle those notifications, there can be no timer callback in the context of that thread.